# webAPI + EF5 dbset contains Local entities which are not in the DB even after a restart of the webAPI project in visual studio

Tags: asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-5

I have been learning about WebAPI + EF5 and have created my first project based on such.

I have a table in the database which has ID, NAME, DESCRIPTION columns, there is a constraint on the NAME column to ensure that NAME is unique for all records.

when I POST say ten entities to the db via the WebAPI project (running in debug in Visual studio) the ten items appear in the physical database - cool.

if I call GET on the webAPI controller, and inspect dbset.Local  I see the 10 items I POSTed, which is perfect.

The problem is that if I stop the WebAPI project in visual studio, open the DB in SQL management studio and delete the physical rows (representing the 10 items I POSTed above)  then restart debugging of the webAPI in visual studio.  If I do a GET request (via fiddler) and inspect dbset via a break point in the get method of the contoler, I find that the 10 items are still the in the dbset.Local property, even though there are no items in the underlying DB.  if I allow the GET to complete effectively calling dbset.ToList()  I get an empty result set.

If I then repost the same 10 items,  the 10 items successfully reach the DB again, but now dbset.Local has 20 items in its Local collection!?

after restarting the WebAPI project, why is dbset.Local not empty, I can stop debugging go for a coffee the restart debugging and dbset.Local collection still has the 20 items in it?  is this a caching issue I am encountering?  is there something I need to do in my project start-up code, to handle this to clear dbset.Local each time the project is re-started in visual studio?

also why is dbset.Local not honouring the constraint of unique names set in the DB and allowing duplicate entries into the dbset.Local collection, should it not throw an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem is that if I stop the WebAPI project in visual studio...

If you have hosted your WebAPI inside ASP.NET (standard WebAPI project in Visual Studio will create such a project type) stopping the debugger won't actually stop the process that is running your application but it will just *detach* the debugger from that application. The process that is running is - if you use IIS Express as development test server for example - the Web Server's worker process and it will keep alive. (It has normally a small icon in the system tray in the bottom right corner of your Windows screen. You can stop the process there, then the process is "really" killed.)

> ... open the DB in SQL management studio and delete the physical rows
>   (representing the 10 items I POSTed above) ...

`DbSet<T>.Local` is a collection in memory. It doesn't "see" that you have deleted rows from the database in another process (SSMS) outside of the EF context.

> ...then restart debugging of the webAPI in visual studio.

If the mentioned worker process is still running restarting the debugger won't start a new process but *attach* the debugger to the existing process. Everything in this process is still there.

> If I do a GET request (via fiddler) and inspect dbset via a break
>   point in the get method of the contoler, I find that the 10 items are
>   still the in the dbset.Local property, even though there are no items
>   in the underlying DB.

Because inspecting or iterating `DbSet<T>.Local` or calling `DbSet<T>.Local.ToList()` doesn't run a database query it doesn't notice that the DB table is empty. It just returns the old data in memory.

> if I allow the GET to complete effectively calling dbset.ToList() I
>   get an empty result set.

Because `DbSet<T>.ToList()` in fact *does* run a database query it will find that the table is empty and return that result to you.

> If I then repost the same 10 items, the 10 items successfully reach
>   the DB again, but now dbset.Local has 20 items in its Local
>   collection!?

Because `DbSet<T>.Local` still had the old results in memory. Although your former `DbSet<T>.ToList()` query to the database returned an empty list to provide the correct query result it does not mean that it cleared the `Local` collection. If it had found a new entity in the database (with a new key value) this entity would have been added to the `Local` collection (showing 11 items then). But a query will never remove items from `Local`.

> after restarting the WebAPI project, why is dbset.Local not empty, I
>   can stop debugging go for a coffee the restart debugging and
>   dbset.Local collection still has the 20 items in it?

Try 10 coffees :) The worker process may shut down automatically after a longer period of time of inactivity. I'm not sure though how long it takes and if it ever happens at all with IIS Express.

> is this a caching issue I am encountering? is there something I need
>   to do in my project start-up code, to handle this to clear dbset.Local
>   each time the project is re-started in visual studio?

Yes, it is (potentially) a very big issue because those entities cached in the `Local` collection indicate that you are reusing the same context instance across multiple web requests. This can lead to wrong results when you rely on `Local` and many other problems and exceptions (for example when you attach an entity that has the same key like an entity that is already in `Local`, etc.). It is generally best practice and recommended to create a new context instance at the beginning of a web request, use it during processing of this single request and then dispose it when the request ends. Disposing a context will free the objects for garbage collection. The `Local` collections of a new context instance will be empty at the next request. (This and how to do it (per controller, manually, dependency injection, etc.) is a special subject on its own. Try to google for "Entity Framework context per request" or similar keywords to get started.)

> also why is dbset.Local not honouring the constraint of unique names
>   set in the DB and allowing duplicate entries into the dbset.Local
>   collection, should it not throw an error?

Entity Framework does not support unique constraints (except the primary key's uniqueness), i.e. it just doesn't know anything about the unique index in the database.

Comment: Brilliant answer thank you.  I had been following the EFMVC project here http://efmvc.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#1544436 I saw that the author was using a Database Factory to serve a singleton context:  I initially thought that we had to keep the context warm, to improve performance on subsequent calls to the database.  but turns out that this is the job of ObjectCOntext and DBContext appears to be an implementation of UnitOfWork which means implementing my own UnitOfWork is redundant with EF.